# How to call getJson multiple times and pass it values after it finishes the first passed item?

Tags: javascript, ajax, getjson

I have a `getjson` call that I want to pass some items to it. I wonder how I can call this `getjson` multiple times and pass them values such as book, pen, paper,... and if those items are on sale display them in different iframes as shown below (for example I want to check 10 items if they are on sale)?

At the moment, my code only processes one item, but I want it to process 10 items and display those items that are on sale.

Furthermore, I want to do this sale checking process for a list of items every 10 min if the user is in the page, without the user having to reload the page. Could you guys show me how this can be done?

```
<script src="http://anyorigin.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$.getJSON('http://anyorigin.com/get?url=http://www.awebsite.com/item=book/&callback=?', function(data){
  var siteContents = data.contents;
  //writes to textarea
  //document.myform.outputtext.value = siteContents;
  var n=siteContents.search("This item is not on sale");
  alert("value of n:"+n);
  if(n=-1) {
    alert("item book is on sale. n:"+n);
    $('#ItemBookWrapper').show();
    //if the passed item is on sale display that item in a iframe if its not on sale go   //to next item. so at
  } else {
    alert("item:book is not on sale");
  }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="ItemBookWrapper" style="display:none">
    <iframe src='http://www.awebsite.com/item=book' height=200 width=200 style='border: none;'></iframe>
  </div>
  <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I wonder how I can call this getjson multiple times and pass them values such as book, pen, paper

If this is the format that the website uses...

```
http://www.awebsite.com/item=book/&callback=?
```

where you'd get the book, the pen the paper... you'd just create a string

```
var getJSONurl = "http://anyorigin.com/get?url=http://www.awebsite.com/item=" + itemType +/&callback=?"
```

and then

```
$.getJSON(getJSONurl, function(data) {
   // your code
}
```

> At the moment, my code only processes one item, but I want it to process 10 items and display those items that are on sale

seeing the JSON structure would help greatly with that one, but, normally with json you'd use...

```
obj = JSON.parse(data);
```

and then use an iterator and to cycle through all of the data objects that you have.

> I want to do this sale checking process for a list of items every 10 min if the user is in the page, without the user having to reload the page

That you'd use a (setInterval)[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval] function...

Where you'd use

```
var interval = window.setInterval(yourJSONfunction(), 60000)
```

where 60000 is time in milliseconds (600 seconds = 10 minutes). When the page loads it'll call every 10 minutes. You could set a variable to be whatever you'd like it to be calling, whether it's books, paper, whathave you. And use that to complete the string.

Comment: thanks tadiou . But how i can call getjson 10 times(on load of page) and pass those 10 items so it filter out those are on sale and display them ?